# Database first and Entity Framework Dynamic Connection String

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, azure

In my WPF app (database-first EF) I need to provide a way to the user to update / modify the database connection string (azure located) at runtime. I am extending the autogenerated partial class of `MyContext` by adding the following method. However I get an error

> A method of same signature already exists

What is the correct procedure of adding dynamically connection string?

Thx

Error message:

> Type 'MyServDataCollection.Models.MyContext' already defines a member called 'MyContext' with the same parameter types

`MyContext` class

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;

public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var model = "MyServDataCollectionModel";
        var providerConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Models.MyServDataCollectionModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyServDataCollectionModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyServDataCollectionModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.database.windows.net;initial catalog=xxxx;persist security info=True;user id=xxxxxxx;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";

        var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        efConnection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        efConnection.ProviderConnectionString = providerConnectionString;

        // based on whether you choose to supply the app.config connection string to the constructor
        efConnection.Metadata = string.Format("res://*/Model.{0}.csdl|res://*/Model.{0}.ssdl|res://*/Model.{0}.msl", model);
        // Make sure the "res://*/..." matches what's already in your config file.
        return efConnection.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please quote the exact error message instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: @Claies Correct, as I am mentioning in the question I am extending the Auto Generated MyContext class so I can include dynamic string in it

Comment: MyContext is marked as partial.  That suggests more code for this class resides in a different file.  In the other file, do you also have a parameterless constructor defined?  The error message suggests that is the problem.

Comment: @TobyCrawford the autogenerated class has the following constructor (  public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext") {  })  which I am extending to provide an dynamic string

Comment: You cannot extend a constructor in the way you are trying.  You have effectively declared a constructor with the same signature as the auto generated one.  You would have to delete the parameterless constructor from the auto generated class to remove the conflict.  This would be problematic though in that it would return when the code auto generation reran.  You may be better served to introduce a factory method for creating instances of your context which can use your GetConnectionString method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is correct. Parameterless constructor is already contained in generated partial class(generated by Visual Studio). To connect using customized connection string you simply call constructor with connection string(or configuration key - see help). I think this constructor is already generated but if is not, then you can simply create it adding this code to your partial class:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(string connectionStringOrKey)
    : base(connectionStringOrKey)
  {
  }
}
```

Method GetConnectionString() you can create as is only with public instead private.

Then simply call

```
MyContext myCtx = new MyContext(MyConnection.GetConnectionString())
```

for example.
Another solution would be to modify your partial class with add static method CreateMyContext:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
  private static string GetConnectionString()
  {
  }

  public static MyConnection CreateMyContext()
  {
    return new MyContext(MyContext.GetConnectionString());
  }
}
```

In this case, but would probably be better to put these methods to another class(extension class ?).

Comment: I implementing exactly the same solution (first part). However now I have a error "The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString." and inner exception says : {"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."}

Comment: Yes, but it is another mistake. This new error will be associated with a bad connection string.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to allow consuming code to continue using a parameterless constructor to create instances of your DBContext, you could amend the T4 template to ensure the auto generated class does not define a parameterless constructor:

Remove the following from the MyContext.Context.tt file:

```
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
    <#

    if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
    {
    #>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    <#

    }

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
    #>
            <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
    <#
        }
    }
    #>
    }
```

This will allow your partial class to work as you expect.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.. but I would really like to avoid the modification of autogenerated files, since the db is still under construction and each time those changes will be overrriden

Comment: You've possibly misunderstood. The above is a modification to the template which is used by the auto generation process.  So when you touch the model and the classes are regenerated the TT file is used as a template to generate CS files.  By making the above modification to the TT (template) file, all subsequent auto regenerations of the partial context file will not include a parameterless constructor.  So you are not modifying the autogenerated CS, but you are modifying the template which creates the autogenerated CS.

Comment: You are totally right:)... still @Stefan answer make me more comfortable. Thanks

Comment: Sure, fair enough.  Be aware though that in @Stefan's solution, the public parameterless constructor is still available; and if someone forgets to use the factory method and uses the constructor instead you will have quite subtle bugs as different DB operations will potentially be going to different databases.